# Avoid const locals that are returned?

Tags: c++, c++14, move-semantics, nrvo

I always thought that it's good to have const locals be const

```
void f() {
    const resource_ptr p = get();
    // ...
}
```

However last week I watched students that worked on a C++ exercise and that wondered about a const pointer being returned

```
resource_ptr f() {
    const resource_ptr p = get();
    // ...
    return p;
}
```

Here, if the compiler can't apply NRVO (imagine some scenario under which that is true, perhaps returning one of two pointers, depending on a condition), suddenly the `const` becomes a pessimization because the compiler can't move from `p`, because it's const.

Is it a good idea to try and avoid `const` on returned locals, or is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: Can't it move from the `const` local anyways via as-if rule?

Comment: In practice, compilers tend to be quite bad at applying (N)RVO in any but the most trivial circumstances, so this is a reasonable concern. A special case is when your "local variable" is actually an argument, where copy elision is sadly forbidden.

Comment: Shouldn't a compiler be able to determine that the lifetime of `p` will end and move anyway?

Comment: @Pixelchemist that's what it does. It effectively puts a `std::move(..)` around it. But `p` is const, so it won't move from it.

Comment: If your type has a copy constructor `Type(Type const&&)`, it will use that. Most people consider that modifying the argument in such a constructor is wrong (it is `const`), but not all, some find it more important that it is an rvalue. In any case, I personally avoid the `const` on such variables.

Comment: Huh, apparently it does matter. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/osnNfTNAr6zLw88w http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pRMMeXBBukM1ohEW Example does not work for clang though, it manages to RVO anyways.

Comment: What's actually the reason for adding `const` to locals, especially if you expect moves from them? In the worst case, you can `const_cast`, assuming you started with a non-`const` object visible outside the body of your function. Can you perhaps clarify?

Comment: By "compiler can't apply NRVO", do you mean that it isn't applied by an implementation even though it is allowed, or do you mean it isn't a candidate for NRVO as per the standard?

Comment: @juanchopanza it's allowed by the spec, but the impl can't do it

Comment: is `resource_ptr` a typedef for raw pointer or what

Comment: @M.M a movable type which has a more expensive copy constructor. vector, shared_ptr..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to try and avoid `const` on returned locals, or is there a better way to deal with this?

Yes.  In fact if `resource_ptr` is a *move-only* type, you will get a compile-time error if you try to return one which is `const`.

This is an example of where "tried-and-true" C++98/03 advice no longer applies in C++11 and forward.

Comment: Is there any case where mandatory elision (C++17) changes things here?

Comment: @MarcGlisse:  I'm still learning the new C++17 rules myself.  But my current understanding is that mandatory elision will only apply to the case where an unnamed temporary is returned.  E.g.:  `return X{};`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant would a rule that makes `p` const till the `return` statement not better, if there are no other references to `p` after the `return` (dtors of locals that are declared after `p`)? The return would ignore the `const`. I don't like these "pitfalls" that wait for you every other line of code.

Comment: @HowardHinnant I haven't read the new rule at all yet, thanks for the quick explanation.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb:  That is certainly a possibility for the future.  To date no one has proposed it (that I'm aware of).  `const` on the local disables RVO (copy elision) and the C++11 "auto-move" rules piggy-backed on the RVO rules for the most part.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I am quite sure I have seen several discussions about that point, I don't think they led anywhere, but I don't remember exactly the arguments on both sides.

Comment: Ah, I still have to learn about the new C++17 rules. Mandatory copy elision sounds interesting.

Comment: @HowardHinnant I think it does not disable RVO, since it says "with the same type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type". When it applies RVO, the data in the const object stays constant: It's only constructed once (in the return value). That's what I was unsure about aswell, but looked it up and it would RVO it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb:  You are correct.  I misremembered.  I would edit that comment, but the edit time has already elapsed.  I was getting mixed up with declaring the return type `const`, which poisons move constructing from such a return type (compile-time error for move-only types).